# Call API inside map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, kendo-ui

I am fairly new to React and am making an app in which I have to call an API inside the map function or so I think.

First, I call an API which returns a list of elements that are rendered in a kendo form like this:

```
import { Form, Field, FormElement } from "@progress/kendo-react-form";
...
const [tempAtr, setTempAtr] = useState([]);
...
const resAtr = await services.getTemplateSessionAtributi(sesijaV);
setTempAtr(resAtr.data.rlista); //tempAtr is filled with a list of elements (attributes)
...
{tempAtr.map((data) =>
<Field
                required={data.required=== 1 ? true : false}
                disabled={data.read_only === 1 ? true : false}
                name={data.name}
                component={ 
                      data.tpodatka_id === 1 ?Input: 
                      data.tpodatka_id === 2 ?Input: 
                      data.tpodatka_id === 3 ?DatePicker: 
                      data.tpodatka_id === 4 ?DropDownList:
                      data.tpodatka_id === 5 ?TextArea :
                      data.tpodatka_id === 6 ?DropDownList:
                      data.tpodatka_id === 7 ?DropDownList:
                      data.tpodatka_id === 8 ?MultiSelect:
                      data.tpodatka_id === 9 ?MultiSelect:
                      Input}
                label={data.name}
                data={ 
                      
                      data.tpodatka_id === (4 || 6 || 7 || 8 || 9) ? 

**call an API and fetch data to fill the dropdown for that specific attribute id ** : 
                      null
                }
                textField={data.tpodatka_id === (4 || 6 || 7 || 8 || 9) ? "name" : null}
                dataItemKey={data.tpodatka_id === (4 || 6 || 7 || 8 || 9) ? "id" : null}
              />)}
```

so in the data section I must call an API with a attribut_id as a parameter so I can fetch dropdown values for that attribute and I don't know how to do it? There can be 1 or 5 or 15 of dropdown attributes, so the only thing I can think of is calling the API inside the map function and assigning values upon it's return.

Help anybody?

Answer (score 0):

Best option is to extract the `dropdown` a separate react component & make the API call in it's `useEffect`. You can pass the `id` as a prop. Example ([Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/drop-down-data-binding-with-hooks-forked-v3dlom?file=/src/App.js))

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

function YearDropDown(props) {
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(true);
  const [items, setItems] = React.useState([]);
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState("2013");
  const { drilldowns } = props;
  React.useEffect(() => {
    let unmounted = false;
    async function getCharacters() {
      const response = await fetch(
        `https://datausa.io/api/data?drilldowns=${drilldowns}&measures=Population`
      );
      const body = await response.json();
      if (!unmounted) {
        setItems(body.data.map(({ Year }) => ({ label: Year, value: Year })));
        setLoading(false);
      }
    }
    getCharacters();
    return () => {
      unmounted = true;
    };
  }, [drilldowns]);

  return (
    <select
      disabled={loading}
      value={value}
      onChange={(e) => setValue(e.currentTarget.value)}
    >
      {items.map(({ label, value }) => (
        <option key={value} value={value}>
          {label}
        </option>
      ))}
    </select>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <YearDropDown drilldowns="Nation" />
    </div>
  );
}
```